# Vertical alignment of long table

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable

How do I vertically center the cell contents of longtable? I tried many solutions didn't work.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{ | P{5cm} | P{8cm}|}
\caption{Architectures used in Experiments  }
\label{con_names} \\

\hline
\thead{Architecture}&\thead{Description} \\  \hline
\endhead
Double-head architecture   & GPT-2 model with languae model head and classification head for persona-chat dataset and Multi-turn chatbot dataset   \\ \hline
Single-head architecture & GPT-2 model with languae model head for Multi-turn chatbot dataset  \\ \hline


\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ, which table-relevant packages you load in the preamble, and -- most importantly -- how the `P` column type is defined.

Comment: Aside: Never, ever encase a `longtable` environment in a `center` environment. Why? `longtable` environments are centered horizontally by default.

Comment: @Mico they are centred by default but there is a stronger reason: it doesn't work. Replace `center` by `flushleft` and that does the same thing, adds spurious vertical space and has no affect on the horizontal alignment. longtable alignments are always the full width of the page so there is no possibility of controling hoirizontal posit.ion from the outside, like `\makebox[\textwidth][l]{abc}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks. My comment was intended as a simple-minded attempt to sell the idea of *not* encasing `longtable` environments in `center` environments. ("Give a person one good reason not to do something foolish, and they just may take your advice. Give them several good reasons, and they just might throw up their hands in despair and ignore your advice entirely.") The comment was evidently a bit too simple-minded...

Comment: @Mico no it was fine really except I read it:-)

Comment: How is the `P` column type you currently use in your `longtable` defined? To vertically center contents in a fixed width column, you could try the `m` column type as for example in `\begin{longtable}{ | m{5cm} | m{8cm}|}`

Answer (score 2):

Just an example with `longtblr` from `tabularray` package.

As leandriis said in their comment, `|m{5cm}|m{8cm}|` works also with `longtable`.

The advantage of `longtblr` is that with `hlines` option you don't need to write `\hline` after every line (and with `vlines` you don't have to put `|` in the column definition).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption={Architectures used in Experiments},
    label=con_names
    ]{
    colspec={m{5cm}m{8cm}}, 
    vlines,
    hlines,
    rowhead=1,
    row{1}={font=\bfseries}
    }
Architecture & Description\\  
Double-head architecture   & GPT-2 model with languae model head and classification head for persona-chat dataset and Multi-turn chatbot dataset   \\ 
Single-head architecture & GPT-2 model with languae model head for Multi-turn chatbot dataset  \\ 
Double-head architecture   & GPT-2 model with languae model head and classification head for persona-chat dataset and Multi-turn chatbot dataset   \\ 
Single-head architecture & GPT-2 model with languae model head for Multi-turn chatbot dataset  \\ Double-head architecture   & GPT-2 model with languae model head and classification head for persona-chat dataset and Multi-turn chatbot dataset   \\ 
Single-head architecture & GPT-2 model with languae model head for Multi-turn chatbot dataset  \\ Double-head architecture   & GPT-2 model with languae model head and classification head for persona-chat dataset and Multi-turn chatbot dataset   \\ 
Single-head architecture & GPT-2 model with languae model head for Multi-turn chatbot dataset  \\ Double-head architecture   & GPT-2 model with languae model head and classification head for persona-chat dataset and Multi-turn chatbot dataset   \\ 
Single-head architecture & GPT-2 model with languae model head for Multi-turn chatbot dataset  \\ Double-head architecture   & GPT-2 model with languae model head and classification head for persona-chat dataset and Multi-turn chatbot dataset   \\ 
Single-head architecture & GPT-2 model with languae model head for Multi-turn chatbot dataset  \\ Double-head architecture   & GPT-2 model with languae model head and classification head for persona-chat dataset and Multi-turn chatbot dataset   \\ 
Single-head architecture & GPT-2 model with languae model head for Multi-turn chatbot dataset  \\ Double-head architecture   & GPT-2 model with languae model head and classification head for persona-chat dataset and Multi-turn chatbot dataset   \\ 
Single-head architecture & GPT-2 model with languae model head for Multi-turn chatbot dataset  \\ Double-head architecture   & GPT-2 model with languae model head and classification head for persona-chat dataset and Multi-turn chatbot dataset   \\ 
Single-head architecture & GPT-2 model with languae model head for Multi-turn chatbot dataset  \\ Double-head architecture   & GPT-2 model with languae model head and classification head for persona-chat dataset and Multi-turn chatbot dataset   \\ 
Single-head architecture & GPT-2 model with languae model head for Multi-turn chatbot dataset  \\ Double-head architecture   & GPT-2 model with languae model head and classification head for persona-chat dataset and Multi-turn chatbot dataset   \\ 
Single-head architecture & GPT-2 model with languae model head for Multi-turn chatbot dataset  \\ 
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]